# summernote 0.7.3 enter causes a new paragraph

Tags: jquery, summernote

I'm using summernote 0.7.3 and habe the problem that it's adding a new paragraph instead of a linebreak. When I hit shift + enter it's adding the line break.

I have found some plugins which aren't compatible to this version anymore. Is there a way to make hitting enter add a line break instead of a paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps for the 0.7.3, but you can change the command being sent for `'ENTER'`, [settings.json](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/5042a63ba55488be88e05de7d8a534136e887df0/src/js/lite/settings.js#L40)

```
$('.my-summernote').summernote({
    keyMap: {
        pc: {
            'ENTER': ''
        },
        mac: {
            'ENTER': ''
        }
    }
});
```